# Class with implicit operator to initialize with default value in method parameter C#

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I have a class where I used implicit operator to initialize the class when string value assigned like this

```
 MyClass db = "";
```

My class is

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static implicit operator MyClass(string value)
    {
        var result = new MyClass()
        {
            Value = value
        };
        return result;
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

This works fine, but when I use MyClass as one of optional parameter in method I can not assign default value.

Example

```
public class Test
{
    public void TestMethod(MyClass my="Default")
    {

    }
}
```

what I need to add in my class so that `TestMethod(MyClass my="Default")` can also work under method paramater

Comment: Just an idea: did you try `TestMethod(MyClass my=(MyClass)"Default")`?

Comment: You'll have to use `MyClass my = null` and then `my ?? "Default"` in your method. You cannot use an instance of `MyClass` as a default value, since only constants are allowed, and the only constant possible for a reference type is `null` -- this is true whether or not you offer up a conversion, since that would still involve creating a non-constant under the hood (which is why the error message complains about there being no *standard* conversion).

Comment: Add an overload method. `public void TestMethod() => TestMethod("Default");`

Comment: On second thought, go with what shingo said. Overloads are generally more reliable than default parameters anyway (since they don't involve injecting values at the call site) and in this case specifically they would leave `null` as a special case.

Comment: I think that you should create constructor for MyClass taking string as a parameter.